# how to add Subject Alt Names to an existing mycomapny.cer certificate in FreeBSD OS?

Tags: x509certificate

When testing under Android P, found a problem with the certificate. The UE was giving an error for the hostname resolution.

As per Adroid P:

**RFC 2818 describes two methods to match a domain name against a certificate - using the available names within the `subjectAlternativeName` extension, or, in the absence of a SAN extension, falling back to the commonName.**

The fallback to the `commonName` was deprecated in RFC 2818 (published in 2000), but support still remains in a number of TLS clients, often incorrectly.

the existing `.cer` has:

```
DirName:/C=DE/ST=xxx/L=xxx 81673/O=my company wireless products /OU=Test/CN=prod.comp.com/emailAddress=xxx@comp.com
```

How to add `subjectAlternativeName` configured to the existing cerficate?

Answer (score 1):

Certificate is digitally signed and tamper-evident. If you modify any bit of the certificate, the signature will be broken and certificate will become invalid.

The only way to get new values there is to acquire new certificate by using same procedures used to get current certificate.